# Force WebARonARCore (Chromium) on Android

Tags: android, cordova, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I'm creating a new Augmented Reality Android application using Cordova. I have in some way to force my mobile to use this web browser:  https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/web/quickstart. Is it possible to do this?

I'm using Cordova to build the Android application, but I don't know how I can force to use this web browser (an .apk file).